# xml + xpath, print element

Tags: php, xml, xpath

```
Notice: Undefined property: DOMNodeList::$id in D:\wamp\www\xml\index.php on line 15
id:

Notice: Undefined property: DOMNodeList::$name in D:\wamp\www\xml\index.php on line 16
name:

<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument();

$xml->load('test.xml');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);

$query = '/people/person[id="33333"]';

$entries = $xpath->query($query);

echo 'id:'. $entries->id.'<br/>';
echo 'name:'.$entries->name.'<br/>';
?>
```

xml file sample:

```
<people>
...
    <person>
        <phone>33333</phone>
        <name>Aadgar</name>
        <last_name>Adas</last_name>
    </person>
...
</people>
```

Comment: `$query = '/people/person[phone="33333"]';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the `id` node doesn't exists...

```
$query = '/people/person[id="33333"]';
```

I think you want:

```
$query = '/people/person[phone="33333"]';
```

Then, you must do:

```
$entries = $xpath->query($query);

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
   echo 'name:'. $entry->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)->nodeValue.'<br/>';
   echo 'last_name:'.$entry->getElementsByTagName('last_name')->item(0)->nodeValue.'<br/>';
}
```

It seems you are mixing up [DOM](http://php.net/DOM) and [SimpleXML](http://php.net/SimpleXML) syntax.

Answer (score 1):

you got the xpath wrong. 33333 is phone not id.

try

```
$query = '/people/person[phone="33333"]';
```

Also

their is no id

```
echo 'id:'. $entries->id.'<br/>';
echo 'name:'.$entries->name.'<br/>';
```

try removeing the id part

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
    $xml = new DOMDocument();

    $xml->load('test.xml');

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);

    $query = '/people/person/phone';

    $entries = $xpath->query($query);

    foreach($entries  as $entry)
    {
       echo $entry;
    }
    ?>
```