# XML xpath attribute value

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

How can i get the attribute value of an xml xpath output ?

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [name] => c
                )

        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [name] => change management
                )

        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [name] => coaching
                )
        )
)
```

This is my Object and i need to extract the values "c", "change management" and "coaching"

This is how my xml look like

```
<Competency name="c">
</Competency>
<Competency name="change management">
</Competency>
<Competency name="coaching">
</Competency>
```

Comment: I'd use DOMDocument parser, it has more options and easier to use. Read this if you like xpath: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492674/xml-xpath-print-element

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($xml->Competency as $Comp) {
   echo $Comp['name']."\n";;
   }
```

result

```
c
change management
coaching
```

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleXmlElement::xpath()` always returns an array of `SimpleXMLElement`objects. Even if the expressions returns a list of attribute nodes. In this case the attribute nodes get converted into `SimpleXMLElement` instances. If you cast them to strings you will get the attribute value:

```
$element = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
foreach ($element->xpath('//Competency/@name') as $child) {
  var_dump(get_class($child), (string)$child);
}
```

Output:

```
string(16) "SimpleXMLElement"
string(1) "c"
string(16) "SimpleXMLElement"
string(17) "change management"
string(16) "SimpleXMLElement"
string(8) "coaching"
```

If this is to much magic, you need to use DOM. It's more predictable and explicit:

```
$document = new DOMDocument($xml);
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//Competency/@name') as $attribute) {
  var_dump(get_class($attribute), $attribute->value);
}

string(7) "DOMAttr"
string(1) "c"
string(7) "DOMAttr"
string(17) "change management"
string(7) "DOMAttr"
string(8) "coaching"
```